# Python Launcher Preferences on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: python, macos, preferences, osx-yosemite

I use some python scripts 2.7.5 with GUI on both OS Win/Mac. Until last month, Mac ran on OSX 10.8 . But since few weeks all Mac was update to OSX 10.10 and now I got a new prompt window about preferences of Launcher everytime i run a script. If I modify these preferences, the next start it would be reset. I tried to reinstall Python and delete plist in library but it still asks for preferences.

Scripts have .pyw extension and Finder is set to use Python Launcher when i double click. It worked fine on 10.8, I had not this window before and I don't care about it. The only preferences I want is to hide this window and just open the GUI script.

Any idea how to do this and why it change with Yosemite ?

[Python Launcher Preferences (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6z8t.png)